# ionic - Confusion about the version

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, ionic3

This is my `package.json` I got from my client:

```
{
  "name": "ionic-hello-world",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^4.1.3",
        "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/platform-server": "4.1.3",
        "@ionic-native/core": "3.12.1",
        "@ionic-native/device": "^3.12.1",
        "@ionic-native/file-opener": "^3.12.1",
        "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^3.12.1",
        "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^3.12.1",
        "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
        "@ng-idle/core": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
        "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
        "@types/ibm-mobilefirst": "0.0.28",
        "@types/jquery": "^3.2.6",
        "ajv": "^5.2.2",
        "ionic-angular": "^3.5.0",
        "ionicons": "3.0.0",
        "ng2-translate": "^4.2.0",
        "rxjs": "5.4.0",
        "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
        "typings": "^2.1.1",
        "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "^2.0.0",
        "grunt": "^1.0.1",
        "grunt-cli": "^1.2.0",
        "grunt-contrib-clean": "^1.1.0",
        "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^1.0.0",
        "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.0.0",
        "grunt-contrib-copy": "^1.0.0",
        "grunt-exec": "^0.4.6",
        "grunt-file-exists": "^0.1.4",
        "grunt-include-replace": "^4.0.1",
        "grunt-string-replace": "^1.2.1",
        "grunt-template": "^0.2.3",
        "typescript": "2.3.4"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    "ios",
    {
      "platform": "ios",
      "version": "",
      "locator": "ios"
    }
  ],
  "description": "online_registration: An Ionic project"
}
```

And when I tried `npm install`, I got this warning:

> npm WARN @angular/animations@4.3.6 requires a peer of
>   @angular/core@4.3.6 but none was installed. npm WARN
>   @angular/platform-server@4.1.3 requires a peer of
>   @angular/animations@4.1.3 but none was installed. npm WARN
>   @ionic-native/splash-screen@3.1.0 requires a peer of
>   @ionic-native/core@3.1.0 but none was installed. npm WARN
>   @ionic-native/splash-screen@3.1.0 requires a peer of
>   @angular/core@2.4.8 but none was installed. npm WARN
>   @ionic-native/splash-screen@3.1.0 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.1 but
>   none was installed. npm WARN grunt-template@0.2.3 requires a peer of
>   grunt@~0.4.0 but none was installed. npm WARN ng2-translate@4.2.0
>   requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.0.0 but none was installed. npm
>   WARN ng2-translate@4.2.0 requires a peer of @angular/http@^2.0.0 but
>   none was installed.

1. How critical is this?
2. Then I check the `ionic info`:

> cli packages: (/Users/xxx/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.1/lib/node_modules)
>
> ```
> @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
> ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2
> ```
>
> global packages:
>
> ```
> Cordova CLI : 6.4.0
> ```
>
> local packages:
>
> ```
> @ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.4
> Cordova Platforms  : android 6.1.2 ios 4.1.1
> Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.0
> ```

It seems like it did not follow `package.json`, which `ionic-angular` is `^3.5.0`. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to delete `node_modules` folder and after that run `npm i`.Hope everything will be fine then.